# Navigating to a specific section of a page in windows 8 Javascript App

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am developing a windows 8 app using JavaScript & HTML.

1. I have a page which has different sections laid horizontally. I have links for these sections in another page. I want the page to load from that specific section (meaning page should start from this section).
2. I am using a grid template and have a listview in the main page. When i click on any item in a group ,navigate to that page and come back to the main page. I want the main screen to load from the section that i have selected before.The screen should automatically scroll to that section like how it is happening from semantic zoom.

Any help in this regard will be of great use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, it should be enough to set the scrollLeft property of the container to the offsetLeft property of the element you want to scroll to.

The second part can be achieved by storing the scrollPosition attribute of the ListView before navigating away and setting it to its old value after navigating back.

Answer (score 0):

As Ma_li said, scroll-left is one solution -- especially for **non** ListView content. The key here is how much of the experience you want to maintain when navigating back. One option (again, for non-listview content) is to find the element you want to be onscreen, and calling `scrollIntoView` on the element. *However*, this only brings the item **on** screen -- it won't bring it all the way to the left (or right, for BIDI languages), it scrolls *just enough* to et the whole element on screen.

*For ListViews*, you should use the [indexOfFirstVisibleItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700691.aspx) (or, indexOfLastVisibleItem) to scroll the listview to the correct location. This is key, because the listview is a virtualized control, this provides the most accurate & reliable method for scrolling the listview position.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dominic & ma_il

I tried document.getElementBy("Id").focus() for the 1st Question and it worked. But i am getting a problem in this.

I have four divs Horizontally say "divA   divB   divC   divD"
Data for the divA is coming from cloud. When i click on the link for divD in the main screen. it is not taking me to the corresponding section for the first time as it takes some time to load the divA. when click on the link for divD second time, it takes to the respective section. It is working if i use setInterval() but the DivA is shown for few seconds when the page loads and then scrolls to divD which is not good.